# Pass arg while importing

Tags: python

How can I pass an argument to a Python module while importing it?

For instance, while running a script from command line, I can do this:

```
python script.py [arg1] [arg2]
```

I want to do the same while I am importing a module in python

I have two modules, `one.py` and `two.py`

**one.py:**

```
name='TestTab'
import two [arg(which i want to be name variable)] 
tweet = Tweet()
```

**two.py:**

```
import sqlalchemy
name= [received arg]
class Tweet():
    __tabname__ = name
    id = Column(String(255))
```

Basically, I want to create a new table every time I import `two.py`, and I want the name of the new table to be passed while importing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really pythonic but a possible simplest way is to expose your variable out

*one.py*

```
import two
two.name = "test"
tweet = two.Tweet()
```

*two.py*

```
import sqlalchemy
name = None
class Tweet():
    __tabname__ = name
    id = Column(String(255))
```

Answer (score 2):

That's not a feature of Python, and you're not using classes well by using class-level variables and no constructor. The way to approach this is to pass the parameter to the constructor of Tweet, and store the data as instance variables.

one.py

```
name='TestTab'
from two import Tweet
tweet = Tweet(whatever_name)
```

two.py

```
import sqlalchemy

class Tweet(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.tabname = name
        self.id = Column(String(255))
```